# Python: getting error list index out of range

Tags: python, indexing

File:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10z5jnxTj9olbsRIGDYiDv6GpLdsb1YAN/view?usp=sharing

This is my code:

```
x,y = [], []
import csv
with open('data2.txt','r') as X:
    reader = csv.reader(X,delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        x.append(row[0])
        y.append(row[1])
```

### Error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-90b7f811ab4f> in <module>()
      5     for row in reader:
      6         x.append(row[0])
----> 7         y.append(row[1])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please, format your code when you are giving one. You can use the backquotes to use a code block

Comment: You can try printing row in the loop, so that you can see where it stops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i you are doing what i think, try to use that line `reader = csv.reader(X,delimiter=',')` The delimiter is what will separate columns, in your file it's `,` not a space

**EDIT**

As said by tdelaney you can also just use `reader = csv.reader(X)`. The comma is the default delimiter for CSV

Comment: and since comma is the default, the `delimiter` parameter isn't needed.